# How can I use labels to filter issues on the github issue tracker?

Tags: github, issue-tracking

I'm using the github issue tracker for the first time, and I'm trying to manage a set of about 50 open issues.   I would like to filter the set using standard Boolean queries over labels.  But all I can figure out how to do is AND queries.
For example, I can show all issues that are labelled both `view/controller` and `easy meat`.  But I do not know how to do any of the following queries:

- Show me all open issues that are labeled `view/controller` but are *not* labeled `easy meat`.
- Show me all open issues that are labeled either `major refactoring` or `needs thought`.
- Show me every open issue that does not have any label.

I've searched and I've RTFM, and I can't find a way to ask these kinds of queries.  **Are such queries even possible?**  If so, how does one ask them?

Comment: Hi Norman! Can you please take a look at [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33007908/1420197)?

Answer (score 10):

This *is* possible since [GitHub introduced the advanced filters](https://github.com/blog/1866-the-new-github-issues).

> Show me all open issues that are labeled `view/controller` but are not labeled `easy meat`.

```
is:open is:issue label:"view/controller" -label:"easy meat"
```

Notice the `-` before `label:` which says *do not give me the issues containing this label*.

> Show me all open issues that are labeled either `major refactoring` or `needs thought`.

This is [not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29136057/1420197) (using `label:A label:B` means *A and B* instead of *A or B*) but you can do two different queries:

```
is:open is:issue label:"major refactoring"
is:open is:issue label:"needs thought"
```

> Show me every open issue that does not have any label.

Use the `no:label` query:

```
is:open is:issue no:label
```

As additional info, you can refer to the [GitHub documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-issues/). And, [`https://github.com/issues`](https://github.com/issues) can be your playgroud–being authenticated, you can search all the issues from repositories you have read access!

Answer (score 2):

Not possible, at least using the GitHub Web app only. There may be 3rd party issue-management Web apps that do this (via GitHub API), but I'm not aware of any that do exactly and only what you want. Check out:

http://gissues.com/

http://huboard.com/

http://githubissues.herokuapp.com/

https://zapier.com/zapbook/github/trello/ (trello integration)

There are ways to achieve nearly what you want using formatted issue naming + searching, as described here:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/129714/how-to-manage-github-issues-for-priority-etc