# How do you keep track of your comments on GitHub issues?

Tags: github

I want to find all the [GitHub](https://github.com/) issues that I commented on. I tried searching for `commenter:mbigras type:issue` like the [Searching issues and pull requests](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-issues/) GitHub article suggests. But that method returns fewer results than the public activity section of my profile.

See both attached images:

### Search method

Doesn't display current results:
[image]

### Profile method

Gets mixed up with other public activity:
[image]

Is there a way to get the full history of my comments on GitHub?

**EDIT**

`author:mbigras type:issue` gives wider results but still not the full history:
[image]

What I'm looking for is a way to quickly view all my comment/issue history in all issues.

**EDIT**

I emailed GitHub about this. Search doesn't match the public activity section because search indexes issues by *creation date* and not *last active date*.

How do you keep organized about which issues you've commented on?

Comment: You only want the issues that you commented ? If no, `author:mbigras type:issue` gives a wider lits.

Comment: Maybe the new project feature allows for some filtering? http://stackoverflow.com/a/39525270/6309

Comment: You can change the sort order by "Recently Updated"

Comment: Being an SE user I went to my profile expecting this information...

Comment: Searching in a repo for `is:issue commenter:@me` works for me.

Answer (score 355, accepted):

Search for `commenter:username` in the main `Github` search box.

For example [commenter:gavinandresen](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=commenter%3Agavinandresen&type=)

To see recent activity, select `Recently updated` from **Sort** dropdown

You can also narrow the search: [is:issue commenter:gavinandresen](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+commenter%3Agavinandresen&type=)

[image]

Comment: It's really weird that recently updated shows the issue comment I just made but newest doesn't.

Comment: it sorts by issue creation date, not by comment creation date

Comment: For those having problem with this: I was able to use this only in the github "root" page, not inside the path of a given repository

Comment: If you happen to be the first commenter of an issue or the creator of the issue, you must do another search for `author:username` and combine the results manually.

Comment: @Toolkit, This doesn't show the issues **created by others, which you have commented on**.

Comment: @Toolkit, You can't find the comment https://github.com/whatwg/url/issues/118#issuecomment-337742987 using the search https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=commenter%3Apacerier&type= .

Comment: @Pacerier of course you can, it's on the second page

Comment: @Pacerier you need to load hidden comments

Comment: FYI, my mistake was picking "newest" instead of "recently updated". "newest" refers to "newest issue" not "newest comment". "recently updated" is better but technically also wrong. It will show issues I commented on years ago but that someone else commented on recently since that "issue" was recently updated. There is apparently no way to search for my own comments shown in a newest to oldest order

Comment: If you want to include issues where you were the *author* too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68116300/470749

Comment: `commenter:@me` also works for the top-level search

Comment: Github should really add a Tab for `Commented` besides `Created`, `Assigned` and `Mentioned`.

Answer (score 40):

I have also been very frustrated when I could not find an issue that I have commented on a while ago. I even did not remember the project it was in. I knew only the problem I was referring to.

Then, I went to the [Notification settings](https://github.com/settings/notifications) on Github and saw there is an **Include your own updates** option that is unchecked by default.

[image: Include your own updates]

Once you check it, Github will send you an e-mail notification about every comment or PR you make. They you probably want to add an appropriate label and filter for emails so Github messages do not clutter an inbox.

My life has changed since then. Now, every time I want to find something I have written on Github, I just search for it in the e-mail notifications.

Comment: I started including these notifications, and yes, it's really lifechanging. No more fear of forgetting stuff that didn't get replies. Also it's the missing piece for having everything centralized in the emails.

Comment: I just wish this was retroactive

Comment: see my reply, should just sort by `Recently updated`

Comment: @fracz, PR meaning?

Comment: @Pacerier Pull Request

Comment: My lifechange is on hold: they took that button off of the interface!

Answer (score 20):

You can view all the issues on Github you have commented on by going to https://github.com/notifications/subscriptions and selecting `Reason` as `Comment`.

This will show all the issues that you've commented on.

You can also filter the issues by selecting other reason such as `Assign`, `Author`, `Manual`, `Mention`, etc. but you can select only one reason at a time. Also, you can filter the issues by repository by selecting the concerned repository from dropdown after clicking `Repository`

Comment: For those looking to get to this page organically: from your notifications page, find "Manage notifications" in the left sidebar and click on the link to display a dropdown list, select "Subscriptions"

Comment: If you want to include issues where you were the *author* too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68116300/470749

Answer (score 5):

Search `All GitHub` using the search term `is:issue author:@me`

[image]

You can also check the following links.

**For all your subscriptions**
https://github.com/notifications/subscriptions

**For all your issues**
https://github.com/issues

**For all your pull requests**
https://github.com/pulls

In case someone is interested to know how to find these links, go to [github's resi api documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest). The URL's are not explicitly described there. However, look for the page names bellow **REFERENCE**.

[image]

If you lowercase the relevant word (for example Issues become issues, Pulls become pulls) and put that after `https://github.com/`, you most probably will find what you are looking for.

Comment: If you want to also include issues where you were a *commenter* (in addition to issues where you were the original author): https://stackoverflow.com/a/68116300/470749

Answer (score 3):

This might be a little late, but there's also another way to find what issues/PRs you have participated in. This method also brings in a lot more things you might be interested in too!

When you are on the website main page, on github.com, use the keyboard shortcuts as described [here](https://help.github.com/en/articles/using-keyboard-shortcuts) to open your pull requests or issues. The shortcut for these is in particular [`g`, `i`] for issues and [`g`, `p`] for pull requests (I remember `g` by go, but whatever works for you.)

After you go to the page directed by these shortcuts you are greeted by an entire screen of goodies you can use! The search bar can be edited and the buttons can be used to make your experience fast!

[image: pr-display-github]

Answer (score 3):

Type `involves:<your username>` in the search box on the GitHub's main page. This will find all the issues that you commented on, was assigned to or mentioned in.

For example, if your username on GitHub is `unclebob`, the search query should look like:

[`involves:unclebob`](https://github.com/search?q=involves%3Aunclebob)

Or if you're logged in to GitHub, then simply:

[`involves:@me`](https://github.com/search?q=involves%3A%40me)

Note the difference between `involves` and similar search qualifiers -  `author` and `commenter`:

- `author` will find only the issues that were **started by you**; if you comment on the issue that was started by someone else, `author` query won't return it in the search results.

  E.g., compare [`involves:unclebob`](https://github.com/search?q=involves%3Aunclebob) and [`author:unclebob type:issue`](https://github.com/search?q=author%3Aunclebob+type%3Aissue).
- `commenter` will find only those issues where you **commented second or later** (creator of the first comment in an issue is considered its author and not a commenter); if you start an issue and then never comment on it, the `commenter` query won't return it in the search results.

  E.g., compare [`involves:unclebob`](https://github.com/search?q=involves%3Aunclebob) and [`commenter:unclebob`](https://github.com/search?q=commenter%3Aunclebob).

In other words, when it comes to searching comments, `author` and `commenter` return only a subset of `involves`' results. So I recommend using `involves` not to miss anything.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to search for multiple users in a single search, use it like in the global search bar without the `OR` logical conjugation:

`commenter:FantomX1 commenter:FantomX1-github`

since the similar google way approach with 'OR' would not work

**commenter:FantomX1 <s>OR</s> commenter:FantomX1-github**

Comment: Note that trying this for `author:` doesn't work (as the first [gets overridden](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61618255/632951)) if you use searchbar at /pulls. GH is really screwed in ignoring bugs for years.

Answer (score 0):

Also, since Github is on the web, any HTTP search engine works, eg Google, Bing, etc. This works to the extent of your search engine's quality and the uniqueness of the writer name.

(Indeed, I actually do this all the time when I need to find any previously written web (engine)-accessible  publication, including those on StackExchange. Names I use are 1 in probably an infinity, so Google often works better than forum search options.)

([Sample Google link](http://google.com/webhp?q=inurl:github.com%20%22pacerier%22%20sample%20foobar%20web%20urls%20%22bob%22%20%22%20%22malfoy%22%20%22etc%22%20etc).)