# How can I find all public comments for a Github user?

Tags: github, user-profile

Until recently I was able to find all my public comments using a link on my profile page. I was using this functionality to keep track of all issues where I have commented, but not contributed anything. It was under a section called "Public Activity".

This function seems to have been removed. I can not find anything about it on the [help page about profiles](https://help.github.com/categories/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/).

Does anybody have any information on when and why this was removed?

Comment: It looks like none of answers gives the answer. As the result we will get list of issues, but not list of all comments =(

Answer (score 184, accepted):

You can do this with an advanced search query. In the `Issues` search box, enter "`commenter:username`".

Or if you want to search a specific repo: "`RepositoryName commenter:username`".

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly the functionality that I wanted. But it's still a shame that the link on my user page is gone and I have to take these extra steps.

Comment: It doesn't work. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37181281/what-technique-do-you-use-to-keep-track-of-your-comments-in-issues-on-github).

Comment: @user25 What do you mean with "Commentator vs. commenter"?

Comment: Is there any comment liker?

Comment: How is this an answer? It says **all public comments** not just for one project?

Comment: Note:  this can also be done from the searchbar at top choosing the current repo, organisation or all of github

Comment: I don't understand how to use this answer. A screenshot would be much welcome, I want to find my own comments across all repositories. (similar to what the OP asked for)

Comment: @MatejJ It works since you can choose to limit the search to either one repo, one organization, or all of Github, as Jerome mentioned. Just try the top search bar.

Comment: The only downside is that the results don't actually link to one's _comments_...

Comment: This returns list of issues, not comments.

Answer (score 29):

This link is quite useful, **it's a live feed of all issues you've commented**.

https://github.com/notifications/subscriptions?reason=comment

[image]

---

Alternatively, this link is also helpful and is probably what the OP asked (**issues where one has written comments**):

https://github.com/search?l=&q=commenter%3AVadorequest+is%3Aissue&type=issues

> Replace "Vadorequest" by the username you're looking for

> You can also use the global search with `commenter:Vadorequest is:issue` to achieve the same result

[image]

---

Also, **if you want to track discussions you participated in**, this link might help:

https://github.com/search?l=&q=commenter%3AVadorequest&type=discussions

> Replace "Vadorequest" by the username you're looking for

> You can also use the global search with `commenter:Vadorequest` to achieve the same result

[image]

---

This 4th (and last) is not related to the OP's question, but might come in handy. **It lists all PR you were requested as reviewer.**

https://github.com/notifications/subscriptions?reason=review_requested

Comment: This should really be a button somewhere in Github.

Comment: Thank you for sharing all of those links/ways to get to the data. I am always surprised on how most cloud apps make it so hard to get to your own comments.

Comment: Yup, I actually had bookmarked those 4 links wayyyy before I wrote that answer. And I remember I looked for those for wayyyy too long to my taste.

Comment: _"**it's a live feed of all issues you've commented**"_ – Not only issues, but also PRs and only those to which you're **still subscribed**!

Comment: @wanna_coder101 The 1st and 4th are actually linked under <Notifications icon> > Manage notifications. ;-)

Comment: @Vadorequest is there also an option to find actions like "thumbs up" or "heart" and so on? I want to find all issue where i added a `Reaction`.

Comment: Not that I am aware of, here is the list of options available in the "advanced search" and I couldn't find anything about "likes". https://github.com/search/advanced?q=commenter%3AVadorequest+is%3Aissue&type=Issues

Answer (score 18):

Type `involves:<username>` in the search box on the GitHub's main page. This will find all the issues that the specified user commented on, was assigned to or mentioned in.

For example, if the user's name on GitHub is `unclebob`, the search query should look like:

[`involves:unclebob`](https://github.com/search?q=involves%3Aunclebob)

Or when searching information about yourself if you're logged in to GitHub, simply:

[`involves:@me`](https://github.com/search?q=involves%3A%40me)

Note, that unlike `involves` similar search qualifiers - `author` and `commenter` - will omit certain results from the search:

- `author` will find only the issues that were **started by the user**; if the specified user comments on the issue that was started by someone else, `author` query won't return it in the search results.

  E.g., compare [`involves:unclebob`](https://github.com/search?q=involves%3Aunclebob) and [`author:unclebob type:issue`](https://github.com/search?q=author%3Aunclebob+type%3Aissue).
- `commenter` will find only those issues where the specified user **commented second or later** (creator of the first comment in an issue is considered its author and not a commenter); if the user starts an issue and then never comments on it, the `commenter` query won't return it in the search results.

  E.g., compare [`involves:unclebob`](https://github.com/search?q=involves%3Aunclebob) and [`commenter:unclebob`](https://github.com/search?q=commenter%3Aunclebob).

In other words, when it comes to searching comments, `author` and `commenter` return only a subset of `involves`' results. So I recommend using `involves` not to miss anything.

Comment: The documentation for `involves`: https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/searching-on-github/searching-issues-and-pull-requests#search-by-a-user-thats-involved-in-an-issue-or-pull-request

Answer (score 3):

Since [GitHub Universe 2016](https://github.com/blog/2256-a-whole-new-github-universe-announcing-new-tools-forums-and-features), the profile page has changed.

It still has a "`Contribution activity`" though, which includes your own comments. But you might need to click on  "Show more activity" to see past the last few weeks.

And you can email yourself your own activity since last June: "[Email updates about your own activity](https://github.com/blog/2203-email-updates-about-your-own-activity)".

Comment: I don't see my comments under "Contribution activity", I only see commits and issues I've created. To get the whole picture I have to click "Show more activity" a bunch of times. The whole profile page seems to have undergone a feature regression :-/

Comment: @BillyTom I agree, that is why I suggest the "mailing list" workaround.

Comment: The "mailing list" workaround seems to be the only way to get a full list of your comments. A list of comments for issues, where you have been mentioned, is available through the web interface: [Issues](https://github.com/issues), in case that is enough. Still, that sort of *"streamlined"* UI is a pretty annoying regression, in my opinion anyway.

Answer (score 1):

**If you want a list of all issues where you either *created* them or were a commenter on them, this link works best:**

https://github.com/notifications/subscriptions?reason=author,comment

Comment: Not only issues and only those to which you're **still subscribed**!