# I commented on someone else's GitHub Issue. How can I find it again?

Tags: github, github-issues, github-search

Just the other day, on some random GitHub Issue,
I left a comment.

Now I want to find my comment,
but unlike Facebook's Activity Log,
since the Issue was not created by me,
nor do I own the repository, well...
the only way to find that activity of mine is to
dig through my browser's history (oops, gone), or remember what I was commenting about,
and try to search for that subject all over*
GitHub Advanced Search is great... if I was the issue originator.

Yes, one one's profile there are one's contributions, but comments on
random issues aren't contributions.

I [assume](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/422706/1118719) I have
posted this question to the right Stack Exchange.

*OK, I found [it](https://github.com/gravitystorm/openstreetmap-carto/issues/4545#issuecomment-1668204450). But how could I have found it if I didn't remember what the content was about. What if all I remembered was it was I who posted a comment a few days ago, but I don't remember what repository or subject etc.?

Comment: if you remember the repo you can use `is:issue commenter:@me `in the git search menu in the Issues page

Comment: I don't think you can. I suppose that would be too much information to display for very active users. Your best shot is probably to enable email notifications for conversations you're participating in (which is the default setting, I believe) and hope someone answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following link:

https://github.com/notifications/subscriptions?reason=comment

See also: [How can I find all public comments for a Github user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39568301/how-can-i-find-all-public-comments-for-a-github-user)

Comment: Thanks! I also found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37181281/how-do-you-keep-track-of-your-comments-on-github-issues