# Web scraping by tag on stack overflow

Tags: python, web-scraping, topic-modeling, stackexchange-api, stackexchange

I would like to do web scraping on this site (`stackoverflow.com`), I was wondering if there was an `API` or some other tool that can be used with Python to get all the comments containing a specific tag.

For example, how do I get all the posts and comments from `10/01/2019 to 01/20/2019` with the `python` tag?

Comment: Maybe have a look at https://api.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I read the page https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/posts 
but I can't create a filter for a specific tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a detailed look at https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/

You can get all questions from a start date to an end date with a particular tag by making use of the [questions](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions) method. You need to pass the specific tag into the `tagged` parameter.

Here is the URL format for that:
`https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?fromdate={start_date}&todate={end_date}&order=desc&sort=activity&tagged={tag}&site=stackoverflow`

For example the below link returns all questions from 1st July, 2019 to 5th July, 2019 with tag `python`:
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?fromdate=1561939200&todate=1562284800&order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=python&site=stackoverflow

For more information on how the date has been formatted in the above URL, you can have a look at [dates](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/dates).

Now that you have the `question_id`, you can make use of [questions/{ids}/answers](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-on-questions) method to get all answers of that question from a start date to an end date.

Here is the URL format for that:
`https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/{question_id}/answers?fromdate={start_date}&todate={end_date}&order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow`

For example the below link returns all answers from 1st January, 2019 to 1st July, 2019 to question with question_id [37181281](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37181281):
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/37181281/answers?fromdate=1546300800&todate=1561939200&order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow

Now you basically have all the posts(questions and answers) from a start date to an end date with a particular tag.

Since, you have the `question_id` and `answer_id` for the posts, you can make use of [questions/{ids}/comments](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/comments-on-questions) method and [answers/{ids}/comments](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/comments-on-answers) method to get the comments on these posts.

Comment: thank you so much! If I can have your availability I would love to ask you one last question, if I wanted to get a lot of data included in different years. For example, from 2016 to 2019, how could I scroll through the pages and increase the maximum output per page?