# Filter GitHub issues matching one of multiple milestones (OR filter)

Tags: filter, github-enterprise, milestone

I'm trying to filter my GitHub issues based on an OR filter of milestones. Specifically, I want to retrieve all issues that are in milestone X *or* milestone Y.

Things I've tried:

- `milestone:X,Y`
- `milestone:"X","Y"`
- `milestone:X milestone:Y`
- `-no:milestone` (aka show me issues that have *any* milestone by way of *not* showing me issues with *no* milestones)

I'm using GitHub Enterprise so don't have the option of installing additional products.

Edit: Seems like per [Can I search github labels with logical operator OR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29136057/can-i-search-github-labels-with-logical-operator-or) searching *labels* by logical OR works (for issues), but the same syntax for milestones did nothing for me.

Comment: This seems like such an easy no-brainer, surely it's all just filtering underneath.  And while it may not be every day that someone says "I want to look across all our releases for the next 6 months" or "show me everything that's not in the current release", those aren't exactly unreasonable questions for your issue management system.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** This answer only works in GitHub Projects, it is not supported in the issues page yet.

---

It is now possible to filter multiple milestones, you just need to separate them using commas. E.g:

```
milestone:"v1.0.0","v1.0.1","v1.0.2"
```

[image]