# Is there a way in Github using the ui to find all Pull Request I am either in process of reviewing or a review was requested of me?

Tags: github

I currently can use the "Review Requested" tab from the https://github.com/pulls page
[image: review request tab]

to find all PRs that I've been requested to review i.e. `is:open is:pr review-requested:myname archived:false` 

 or I can do `is:open is:pr reviewed-by:myname` to get all the PRs that I've started reviewing that are still open.

But is there a way to get a combined list?
I tried `is:open is:pr archived:false (review-requested:myname OR reviewed-by:myname)` but get no results.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61618255/5987698) may help.