# How to search on GitHub with OR/AND operators

Tags: github

How can I search an issue on GitHub that contains keywords "java" AND ("python" OR "C++")? Is it possible to represent a search with these logical operators like OR/AND?

Comment: What do you want to search? Is it a user, is it various repositories, pull requests or maybe issues?

Comment: @georgekrax An issue in a repo whose description and comments contain keywords like "java" AND ("python" OR "C++")

Comment: See also "[Can I search GitHub labels with logical operator OR?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68621781/6309)"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out GitHub does not provide functions to achieve the searching logics like ANR/OR. The solution I figured out is to write a crawler that implements the searching logics.

Answer (score 4):

Well, GitHub does not work like **StackOverflow**, but there are some ways to achieve what you want to accomplish. Start by using the `type` label, like this `type:issue`, then you can use the `in` qualifier, like this `python in:title,body`, which will search titles that contain the word `python`. [Here](https://docs.github.com/en/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-issues-and-pull-requests) is a more detailed (reference) of GitHub's Docs, which might help you with your issue.

I hope this helps you, but as much as I searched I could not find conditional search features on GitHub's search, but there are some pretty useful labels (qualifiers) that you can benefit from.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! In fact I have resolved my problem with a crawler that implements the searching logics.