# What is the GitHub search syntax for mandatory search terms?

Tags: github, text-search

What is the syntax for specifying that words must appear in the results of a GitHub search? - Similar to using the double quotes around words in a Google search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quotations are only used for [query with a space in them](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/getting-started-with-searching-on-github/understanding-the-search-syntax#use-quotation-marks-for-queries-with-whitespace).

By default, a word is supposed to appear is the results. No quotes needed.

If you have several words, you can try:

```
word1 AND word2 AND word3
```

Although [AND/OR operator do not seem to be supported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63951018/6309).