# Using logical operators when filtering Github issues

Tags: github, github-issues

It seems like all the filters currently use logical `AND` by default. E.g. `is:issue label:bug bug in:title` basically does `is:issue && label:bug && bug in:title`.

My question is, whether it’s possible to make a query like: `is:issue && label:bug || bug in:title`.

Related: [Can I search github labels with logical operator OR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29136057/can-i-search-github-labels-with-logical-operator-or), but this deals with logical or within labels only. I am looking for something more generic.

Edit: According to [Search REST API docs](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/search#limitations-on-query-length), operators are supported

> have more than five AND, OR, or NOT operators

but I couldn't find anything related.

Answer (score 0):

The more generic search documentation is "[Understanding the search syntax](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/getting-started-with-searching-on-github/understanding-the-search-syntax)", based on "[About searching on GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/getting-started-with-searching-on-github/about-searching-on-github)"

> GitHub search uses an ElasticSearch cluster to index projects every time a change is pushed to GitHub.
> Issues and pull requests are indexed when they are created or modified.

While the Elasticsearch syntax does include [boolean operator](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_boolean_operators), nothing in the generic GitHub search documentation indicates `OR` is supported (for now, July 2022).