# GitHub: filter for issues that are either assigned to somebody or somebody is mentioned

Tags: github, issue-tracking, github-issues

Is there an option how to show all issues that are either assigned to me **or** that I'm mentioned in at the same time? Filtering by using the dropdown menu allows only to check for one of those and using `is:open assignee:@me mentions:@me` filters for all issues for which both constraints are true (basically `&` instead of `|`)

The first answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14917354/how-can-i-use-labels-to-filter-issues-on-the-github-issue-tracker) from 8 years ago suggests it is not possible to use an "or" query. Does this still hold true?

What is the best alternative to filter for all issues that are relevant for me, ideally in the whole organization - third party tools?

Comment: Try `is:open @myhandle`

Comment: And try the notification hub: https://github.com/notifications

Comment: No `or` option in search still.

Answer (score 4):

[The `involves:user` may be useful here](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/searching-on-github/searching-issues-and-pull-requests#search-by-a-user-thats-involved-in-an-issue-or-pull-request):

> ### Search by a user that's involved in an issue or pull request
>
> You can use the involves qualifier to find issues that in some way involve a certain user. The involves qualifier is a logical OR between the author, assignee, mentions, and commenter qualifiers for a single user. In other words, this qualifier finds issues and pull requests that were either created by a certain user, assigned to that user, mention that user, or were commented on by that user.

Simply searching for the user's Github handle may be useful too.

Using a tool like `gh` (github cli) will allow you to lest and filter items too. A script can easily concatenate the results:

```
gh issue list --search "involves:@me is:open"
```

You can have it spit out json as well by adding `--json`, that way you can parse and further process the results as well.